# End(Xldown) vs End(xlup)

Tags: excel, vba

I have a simple worksheet of just 2 columns and 14 rows in which all cells within the range are filled. I was testing out counting the number of rows using both the xlup and xldown formula as follows:

```
Worksheets("sheet1").cells(rows.count,1).end(xlup).row 
Worksheets("sheet1").cells(rows.count,1).end(xldown).row
```

I was thinking that both should return me the number 14 but only the xlup returned 14 and the xldown returned 1048. Which is the total number of rows in the sheet. When I pressed CTRL down, which should be the xldown purpose, it did bring me to the bottom of the selection of 14 rows and not the entire excel sheet so I’m not too sure why the code didn’t work here.

Comment: In the second bit you are starting at the bottom and trying to go down.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So why does the xldown not work in this instance? I thought it would go down to the last occupied cell.

Comment: But you are starting from the last row in the sheet. You can’t go down any further. It doesn’t wrap. You’d have to start at row 1.

Comment: ahh  i see i see. Would you care to share the syntax  for that? Do i need to select the top cell first?

Comment: Yes it's just `Worksheets("sheet1").cells(1,1).end(xldown).row` but it will give you the wrong result if there are blanks in the middle, and if only A1 is filled it will go to the very last cell.